# Convert zoned timestamp to com.google.protobuf.Timestamp

Tags: java, kotlin, timestamp, rfc3339

In my custom API that I am creating using Swagger, I need to input a timestamp.

In my YAML file I have defined the format of my input parameter as `date-time` as mentioned on the Swagger webpage [date-time – the date-time notation as defined by RFC 3339, section 5.6, for example, 2017-07-21T17:32:28Z](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#string)

I want to convert the resulting zoned timestamp to `com.google.protobuf.Timestamp` but I don´t know how to do that and need help. I am using Kotlin.

So far I´ve tried implementing some of the Java examples from StackOverflow (after converting to Kotlin), for instance:

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")
        .format(new Date()));
```

and

```
LocalDateTime withoutTimezone = zoneDateTime.toLocalDateTime();
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(withoutTimezone));
```

None of the examples seem to work since I need input parameter in `com.google.protobuf.Timestamp` format, which the above examples do not result in.

Any help would be appreciated regarding how to convert timestamp.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you show it what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven’t tested, but from reading the `com.google.protobuf.Timestamp` documentation this seems to be an option:

```
    String exampleInput = "2020-08-27T20:13:10+02:00";
    Instant javaTimeInstant = OffsetDateTime.parse(exampleInput).toInstant();
    com.google.protobuf.Timestamp ts = com.google.protobuf.Timestamp.newBuilder()
           .setSeconds(javaTimeInstant.getEpochSecond())
           .setNanos(javaTimeInstant.getNano())
           .build();
```

I am using Java. You can probably hand translate to Kotlin yourself?

**Documentation link:** [`com.google.protobuf.Timestamp`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Timestamp)